# Convert data from columns to replicates in Graphpad Prism

Tags: graphpad-prism

I'm looking for a way to convert data from columns to replicates in Graphpad Prism v7.02.

Here is a screenshot of some sample data in a column:

[image: Sample data in column]

Here is a screenshot of what I'm hoping to convert it to:

[image: Data as Replicates]

When I try to do this using

```
Analyze Data -> Transform, Normalize... -> Transpose X & Y
```

the output gives me each row in a separate column

[image: Result of Transpose X and Y]

This would be OK if I could find a way to convert two adjacent columns into replicates, but I can't find that. I do know how to do it using Miscrosoft Excel, but I would prefer a one-step process.

Please let me know if you have suggestions.

Comment: If someone with more than 300 reputation points would be so kind, please will you create a tag "graphpad-prism" and I will assign this question to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Copy -> Paste Special

Copy the data from cells the first data table ("Data 1") Group A, rows 1 through 6 using Control-C

[image: Select all 6 cells to copy]

Create a new "Grouped" data table with the desired number of replicates ("Data 2").

Paste the data from "Data 1" into "Data 2" using Paste Special
* On the "Source" tab select "Insert and maintain link"
* On the "Placement" tab select "Transpose. Each row becomes a column"

[image: Paste Special Source]

[image: Paste Special Placement]

Alternatively, right click the destination cell and Paste Transpose -> Link

Copy over column and row names similarly, with or without transposing.

The data in "Data 2" will now be updated when "Data 1" is updated, and can be used for analysis and to make graphs.

[image: Result]